# Getting the first n elements of a list in Common Lisp?

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

How would I get the first `n` elements of a list?

```
CL-USER> (equal (some-function 2 '(1 20 300))
                '(1 20))
T
```

I am absolutely certain this is elementary, but help  a brother newb out.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Check out the [`SUBSEQ`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_subseq.htm) function.

```
* (equal (subseq '(1 20 300) 0 2)
         '(1 20))
T
```

It may not be immediately obvious, but in Lisp, indexing starts from 0, and you're always taking half-open intervals, so this takes all the elements of the list with indices in the interval [0, 2).

Comment: This has the unfortunate restriction that it will fail *in runtime* if the sequence is smaller than the ending index, which is a pity, because asking for the length before is highly inefficient. So how to proceed in this case?

Comment: Well, looking at Practical Common Lisp: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html comes the right answer: `(loop
  for item in list
  for i from 1 to 10
  do (something))` where that `something` could be collecting `item`.

Comment: @DiegoSevilla Sometimes having the code fail at runtime when you don't have enough elements in your list is exactly the behavior you're looking for. A lot of idiomatic Common Lisp code builds fixed-size data structures out of conses instead of using `DEFCLASS` or `DEFSTRUCT`, and in those instances, if you don't have enough elements, getting tossed into the debugger immediately is the best thing that can happen to you.

Answer (score 6):

The above answer is of course perfectly correct, but note that if you're using this just to compare against another list, it would be more performance-efficient to walk both lists in-place, rather than consing up a new list just to compare.

For example, in the above case, you might say:

```
(every #'= '(1 20 300) '(1 20))
=> t
```

Answer (score 1):

Tinkering with the core CL functionalities:

```
(defun first-n (n list)
  "Returns the first N elements of the LIST."
  (butlast list (- (list-length list) n)))

(first-n 2 '(a s d f g))        ;(A S)
```

Comment: This has some unneeded overhead because it has to walk the entire list to determine the list length first.  It will even fail if the list is circular.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive:

```
(defun first-n (list n)
  "Returns the first n elements of the list."
  (when (not (zerop n))
    (cons (first list) (first-n (rest list) (1- n)))))

(first-n '(a b c d e) 3)        ;(A B C)
```

With `loop`:

```
(defun first-n-loop (list n)
  "Returns first n elements of the list."
  (loop for i below n
     collect (nth i list)))

(first-n-loop '(a b c d e) 3)       ;(A B C)
```

Comment: The recursive version will blow the stack on long lists, even in those implementations that do tail call optimization.  The loop version has quadratic runtime because it walks the list for each element.  Better: `(loop :repeat n :for x :in list :collect x)`.

Comment: Note that the previous comments means it will blow the stack on long *result* lists, if n is large.  And this also brings us to the bug: if n is larger than the list is long, it will return a list of length n padded with nil (well, I think CL is similar enough to Emacs Lisp in this regard; I didn't test it in a real CL :D)

Answer (score 0):

@Pillsy has the answer. SUBSEQ.

But there is a difficulty with SUBSEQ that if you specify beyond the end of the list, you get an error. This is overcome by using LENGTH and MIN:

```
(defun first-n (n lst)
  (subseq lst 0 (min (length lst) n)))
```

For example:

```
CL-USER 11 > (first-n 3 (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 6))
(1 2 3)

CL-USER 16 > (first-n 10 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 6))
(1 2 3 4 5 6 6)
```

Answer (score -1):

Had to download a lisp command line... but:

```
(defun head-x (a b)
   (loop for x from 1 to a 
         for y = (car b) do 
            (setq b (cdr b)) 
         collect y))
```

so:

```
(head-x 2 '(a b c d))
  '(a b)
```

Comment: Just use `(loop :repeat a :for x :in b :collect x)` as your function body. Much simpler.

Comment: Thanks... been years since I actually did any lisp.  Thought it be fun to answer a question!

Answer (score -1):

```
(defun pncar (n L)
  (setq L_ (list (nth 0 L)))
  (setq i 0)
  (if (and (< n 1) (< n (length L)))
    (setq L_ '())
    (repeat (- n 1) (progn
                      (setq i (+ i 1))
                      (if (/= nil (nth i L))
                        (setq L_ (append (list (nth i L)) L_))
                        (setq L_ '())
                        )
                      )
      )
    )
  (setq L_ (reverse L_))
  )
```

Examples:

```
(pncar 0 '(0 1 2 3))
    nil
(pncar 1 '(0 1 2 3))
    (0)
(pncar 2 '(0 1 2 3))
    (0 1)
(pncar 3 '(0 1 2 3))
    (0 1 2)
(pncar 4 '(0 1 2 3))
    (0 1 2 3)
(pncar 5 '(0 1 2 3))
    nil
```

Answer (score -4):

(butlast '(1 20 300) (- (list-length '(1 20 300)) 2))

Should be made into a function/macro.

P.S. [This page](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/academics/courses/325/readings/graham/generators.html) might be useful. See function 'extrude'.

Comment: Definitely not a good idea to compute the length of a list for getting some elements from the front. Unlispy!